# How do I detect my page control values are changed and what values are changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have asked a similar question earlier, but this time i need a method that will detect any change made on any control of the page with old and new values in a combined string to maintain history of that particular change. Say if a user made in 4 fields of a page the method will be able to detect the change and create a string with change in old and new values.

Note - My page controls are using Class Properties to display values.

Comment: When do you want to log the changes, on every postback or before you safe it to the database? Do you want to log these changes also in the database or where do you want to store them?

Comment: Yes i want it to log to database. After a button save operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple opinion is :

Just put your "Class" properties into Session (it means : put your data(s) into Session which is load data(s) from default). After that on your **Save** button **event**, you can compare your Session which is contains old data(s) with new user changes data(s). At this case you can create your own method (at your page control) to detect values changes.